# Declaring new instance of Object results in OutOfMemoryFailure. Why?

Tags: java, android, object, out-of-memory, instantiation

I'm having trouble understanding something. I have a separate Listener class (Android) that takes care of all of my listeners in an activity.

When I set an onclickListener with:

```
.setOnClickListener(new ListenerActivity());
```

It works fine. However, I want to create

```
public ListenerActivity myListener = new ListenerActivity();
```

and access it with:

```
SaveButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

which should make sense since instead of creating an instance of a new listener activity every time, I would create a new instance once and re-use it. However I get this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 600680 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 57MB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 602112 bytes where largest contiguous free 438272 bytes)
        at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:343)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:61)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.-wrap0(RuntimeInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

why is this not working?

Edit:

This is my main class:

```
public class EditPageMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

This is my Listener Class:

```
public class EditJobListenerActivity extends EditJobMainActivity
    implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnClickListener,
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
```

Comment: This seems weird, generally you don't create activities on your own, please post more of your code or explain why you're creating activities.

Comment: What do you mean by you don't create activities on your own? Honestly, I was going for an abstract Class which wasn't an Activity, but I was encountering a problem where in order to import Toast I needed to implement like 50 other methods so that's why I'm using an extends. I'll show you in an edit in a moment.

Comment: That's not how you do it, see below for the correct way to do it. If you are set on a static listened, just pass it a reference to the application (not activity!) context, and it can show toasts.

Comment: I tried the getApplicationContext() and getContext() and I think one more that was suggested and none of them worked... in any case I understand my way is a little less than conventional, is it "bad"? as in, does it heavily bog down the program by doing it this way? Also, could it have been giving that error because of the fact that ListenerActivity extends MainActivity?

Comment: It's very bad and yes it will bog down your program because you're wasting RAM. Instead create a new class which you pass the application context, then you can use it, getContext is only available from classes governed by android (activity, service, broadcast receiver, etc), in other classes you have to supply it to your class.

Comment: Wait, when you say Instead, create a new class... I'm under the impression that as we stand right now, creating a new class for Listeners bogs down RAM. Am I under the right impression?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89523/discussion-between-user3654055-and-johanshogun).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call new on an Activity, instead, you should let the Android OS do that for you.

```
SaveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListenerActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) for details about starting activities.

Comment: The point is that adding onClick to every button, every checkbox, every spinner, everything that has a click or select or whatever will bog down the code visually, and I'm going for readability for future edits. Unless it makes the program size significantly smaller or faster, what I'm intending is: NewListenerClass implements [all listeners that matter] { @override public void onClick(View v) { If (v.getId() == x) then y, and etc.